# Top line padding with Nvd3 chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have this problem with my charts with angular-nvd3, they are `linePlusBarChart` and they work fine but if I change the interpolation to `cardinal` I get a line like that one showed in the screenshot.

How can I solve that?

My chart options:

```
vm.chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'linePlusBarChart',
        height: 450,
        margin: {
            top: 0,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 50
        },
        focusEnable: false,
        duration: 250,
        forceY: [0],
        groupSpacing: 0.5,
        interpolate: 'cardinal',
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: false,
            showMaxMin: false,
            tickFormat: function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%b %y')(new Date(d));
            }
        },
        y1Axis: {
            showMaxMin: false,
            tickFormat: function(d) {
                if (d > 0) return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d);
            }
        },
        y2Axis: {
            showMaxMin: false,
            tickFormat: function(d) {
                if (d > 0) return d3.format(',f')(d);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[image: The chart]

Comment: Hello, i am facing the same problem. So, i wonder how did you solve this problem? thanx in advance

Comment: Look at myself answer below.

Comment: Thanx a lot.your answer is similar to the solution that i implemented

Answer (score 1):

I solved it manipulating the Y axis with the `forceY` parameter:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4], // the chart values this is only for example
    maxY = 0,
    forceY = [0];

if (values && values.length) {
    maxY = _.max(values, function(o) {
        return o.y;
    });
}
if (maxY && maxY.y) {
    forceY = [0, (maxY.y * 15 / 100) + maxY.y];
}
```

And then just add the parameter `forceY: forceY` to the chart